# Readable exception information when testing DateTime objects in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit

When testing DateTime objects in PHPUnit (3.7.22), I am making the assertion like this:

```
$this->assertEquals(date_create('2014-01-01'), $myobject->getDate());
```

Works nicely till you get an exception, and the exception in not clear enough (like for primitives where is clearly states for example that 1 does not equal the excepted 2).

```
PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
```

I could pass the `$message` parameter to the `assertEquals` method, with a string containing the object value, but I feel it could go easier.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
$expected_date = new DateTime('2014-01-01');
$this->assertEquals($expected_date->format('Y-m-d'), $myobject->getDate()->format('Y-m-d');
```

This would make you error message say something like "failed asserting that '2014-02-03 matches expected 2014-01-01'

Answer (score 1):

I had a poke around the phpUnit source, and don't see any hook to allow better display. What I usually do is what you already mention in your question:

```
$this->assertEquals(date_create('2014-01-01'), $myobject->getDate(), print_r($myobject,true) );
```

OR:

```
$this->assertEquals(date_create('2014-01-01'), $myobject->getDate(), print_r($myobject->getDate(),true) );
```

depending on which is more useful, case-by-case.

I do this anyway, because often I want to include other helpful data in the message, perhaps some previous calculations, to give it context. I.e. to know why a test is failing I often need to know more than just the two objects that should've been equal.